# Heroku, Java App, Maven: Cannot find main class

Tags: java, maven, heroku

I'm having problems getting a simple java app built with Maven to run on Heroku. Can anyone spot what's wrong here? I cannot run this locally either. I will say that I'm not terribly experienced with Maven, so my guess is that the pom file has a misconfiguration, but I don't know what it is.

**Log upon starting:**

```
2023-02-21T16:50:32.886966+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2023-02-21T16:50:33.096908+00:00 app[worker.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
2023-02-21T16:50:33.158703+00:00 app[worker.1]: Error: Could not find or load main class com.heroku.chiller.service.WorkerProcess
2023-02-21T16:50:33.292958+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2023-02-21T16:50:33.344761+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

**WorkerProcess.java:**

```
package com.heroku.chiller.service;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import io.dropwizard.Application;
import io.dropwizard.setup.Environment;
import io.dropwizard.configuration.EnvironmentVariableSubstitutor;
import io.dropwizard.configuration.SubstitutingSourceProvider;
import io.dropwizard.setup.Bootstrap;


public class WorkerProcess extends Application <ServiceConfiguration> {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(com.heroku.chiller.service.WorkerProcess.class);

    
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        //new WorkerProcess().run(args);
    }


    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "chiller-kafka-to-postgres";
    }


    @Override
    public void initialize (Bootstrap <ServiceConfiguration> bootstrap) {
        bootstrap.setConfigurationSourceProvider(
            new SubstitutingSourceProvider(bootstrap.getConfigurationSourceProvider(),
                    new EnvironmentVariableSubstitutor()
            )
        );
    }


    @Override
    public void run (ServiceConfiguration config, Environment env) throws Exception {
        KafkaConsumerService consumerService = new KafkaConsumerService(config.getKafkaConfig());
        env.lifecycle().manage(consumerService);
    }
}
```

**Procfile:**

```
worker: java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes/com/heroku/chiller/service com.heroku.chiller.service.WorkerProcess config.yml
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.heroku.chiller.service</groupId>
  <artifactId>chillerkafkatopostrgres</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
       <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
       <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
     <slf4jVersion>1.6.1</slf4jVersion>
     <dropwizard.version>0.9.2</dropwizard.version>
 </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
      <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
      <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
      <artifactId>dropwizard-views-mustache</artifactId>
      <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
      <artifactId>dropwizard-assets</artifactId>
      <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.loginbox.heroku</groupId>
      <artifactId>dropwizard-heroku-config</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.jkutner</groupId>
      <artifactId>env-keystore</artifactId>
      <version>0.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-declarative-linking</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2</version>
  </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>jcenter</id>
      <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>Eclipse Paho Repo</id>
        <url>https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.1.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
            <programs>
                <program>
                    <mainClass>com.heroku.chiller.service.WorkerProcess</mainClass>
                    <name>worker</name>
                </program>
            </programs>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <phase>package</phase><goals><goal>assemble</goal></goals>
              </execution>
          </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

**Project structure**

[image]

**What I expect and what I've tried:**
I expect that the program will run once deployed. I have tried adjusting the pom file and procfile in many ways no to avail. I also peer-reviewed with a colleague and they can't find the problem either.

Comment: If nothing else the classpath should be the **root** of the classes..

Comment: I added an image of the project structure. Did you spot a place where it isn't correct?

Comment: Your Procfile specifies the classpath as starting deep inside the classpath. The classpath starts at the **root** of the class hierarchy..

Comment: Can you be more specific? I've adjusted the classpath to `worker: java -cp com/heroku/chiller/service com.heroku.chiller.service.WorkerProcess config.yml`, this produces the same error. Or is it supposed to be `worker: java -cp target/classes/ com.heroku.chiller.service.WorkerProcess config.yml`?

Comment: The root of the classpath is the **top** of the classes: whatever directory `com` is in. It’d be worth taking a step back and checking out the Java docs/tutorials around classpaths.

Comment: OK, so what I understand about the -cp flag is this. `-cp <path to root of classpath> <package and main class name>` So if `java -cp target/classes/ com.heroku.chiller.service.WorkerProcess` does not work, then why doesn't it work?

Comment: No clue; depends on what’s being deployed and how. If your code requires all the dependencies in the Pom at runtime they also need to be on the classpath whether locally or on Heroku. You may be better served with some Java and Maven tutorials than SO until the basics are worked out. You may also want to look at the exec and shade (or other über-jar) plugins.